# Why does using achemso turn off bookmarks?

Tags: hyperref, achemso

I like using sections as bookmarks when editing. However, when I use `achemso` it turns these off.

MWE1 produces bookmarks properly.

```
%\documentclass[journal=cgdefu]{achemso}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{This is a title}
\author{Canageek}
%\affiliation{Department of Chemistry, Simon Fraser University, 8888 University Drive, Burnaby, B.C., Canada}
%\email{This is an email}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\section{Experimental}

\end{document}
```

MWE2, however, does not:

```
\documentclass[journal=cgdefu]{achemso}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{This is a title}
\author{Canageek}
\affiliation{Department of Chemistry, Simon Fraser University, 8888 University Drive, Burnaby, B.C., Canada}
\email{This is an email}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\section{Experimental}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard settings in `achemso` turn off section numbers by effectively making `\section` behave like `\section*`. You therefore need to use `\SectionNumbersOn` to enable section numbering: this will also generate PDF bookmarks for the sections. If you want numberless sections but also want `\SectionNumbersOn` then you'll need to use `\section*` in place of `\section`, as in any other document.